# How do I fetch CoreData subentities and find their class name?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am trying to build a generic `SyncEngine`. In it, I fetch a given parent entity as follows:

```
__block NSArray *newRecords = nil;
[[[CoreDataController sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:className];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"serverID = nil"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    newRecords = [[[CoreDataController sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}];
```

I am looking for a way to do the following:

1. Test if the retrieved entity has a set of "children".
2. If so - I want to find the class name of its children.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean child entity (className being the parent entity) or entities linked via relationships?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the difference...

Comment: className is an entity (NSManagedObject) that has a relationship to another entity (defined in the model). I fetch className from CoreData (in the code above) and want a way to get the name of the child entity

Comment: OK, thanks. You can also have one entity inherit from another (often "abstract") one. See [Entity Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002328-SW5) in the Core Data Programming Guide.

Answer (score 0):

Your child entities are of the same base class.
Add a property on that base class of type `NSString` (lets call it `className`).

in your `<BaseEntity>.h` (to generate the file go to Editor->Create NSManagedObject Subclass):
implement `- (void) awakeFromInsert` like so:

```
- (void) awakeFromInsert
{
    self.className = self.entity.name;
}
```

Your fetch request should now be:

```
NSExpressionDescription* idDesc = [NSExpressionDescription new];
[idDesc setName:@"objectID"];
[idDesc setExpression:[NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject]];
[idDesc setExpressionResultType:NSObjectIDAttributeType];

NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"<BaseEntity>"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent = %@",parent.objectID];
[request setResultsType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"className",idDesc]];
```

This request will return the an array of dictionaries with your requested data.